# Making a whiteboard from a screenshot

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins, internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know something that could boost my efforts in creating such thing that let's user's of my website shot screenshots of it and then draw on top of them/take notes?

Are there already built-in technologies in browsers or already made plugins that do something similar?

I will appreciate any kind of help or hint.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome, there is [Web Paint](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-paint/emeokgokialpjadjaoeiplmnkjoaegng). If you are just painting on web.

If you want to save that forever, you may want to use Evernotes or MS Office OneNote, since it is far more difficult to capture the web page through JavaScript in the web page.